# javascript location works on localhost not server

Tags: javascript, server, location, localhost, assign

I have this code:

```
$('.contentBox').click(redirect);

function redirect () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname
    location.assign(pathname.replace('index.html', $(this).find('a').attr('href')));
    return false;
}
```

Which works fine on localhost, but on server it just refreshes the main page. It only works if I actually visit another page on my menu first, and then go back to my page with the function...what gives?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are doing is not the best way to redirect a user. Use directly href for the same.

Now coming to your code.
It will always refresh as long as pathname will not contain index.html, what you are assigning to **location.assign()** is this:

```
pathname.replace('index.html', $(this).find('a').attr('href'))
```

if pathname will not contain index.html it will return the pathname itself which is your original path. Hence you see a page refresh.

Try adding `console.log(pathname)` to verify it.

```
     $('.contentBox').click(redirect);

    function redirect () {
        var pathname = window.location.pathname
        console.log(pathname)
       if(pathname.indexOf('index.html') > -1){
          location.assign(pathname.replace('index.html', $(this).find('a').attr('href')));
          return false;
       }
    }
```